# Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Ex1_1 {
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    @SuppressWarnings("all")
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Введите числа для вычисления \nсреднего арифметического!!!");
    int a = 0;
    int summ = 0;

    while (true){
        System.out.print("число " + (a + 1) + ": ");
        int ch = sc.nextInt(a + 1);

        if (ch == 0000){
            break;
        }
        ch = +ch;
        summ = summ + ch;
        ch++;
        }

    int i = summ / a;
    int j = summ % a;
        if (summ % a == 0) System.out.println("Ответ : " + i);
        else System.out.println("Ответ : " + i + " с остатком : " + j);
    }
    }
```

Это код программы.
При компиляции происходит следующее: Компилятор выполняет цикл один раз, а на второй раз выдает такую ошибку:

```
Введите числа для вычисления 
среднего арифметического!!!
число 1: 123123
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException: radix 1
>   less than Character.MIN_RADIX     at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown
>   Source)   at Ex1_1.main(Ex1_1.java:13)

если я заменю ***int ch = sc.nextInt(a + 1)*** на ***int ch = sc.nextInt()*** , то будет бесконечный цикл

Введите числа для вычисления 
  среднего арифметического!!!
 
 число 1: 1
 
 число 1: 2
 
 число 1: 4
 
 число 1: 3
 
 число 1: 5
 
 число 1: 7
 
 число 1: 8
 
 число 1: 5

  число 1: 4

  число 1:

Comment: Вам либо нужно придумать какое-то адекватное условие выхода из цикла, либо сначала запрашивать кол-во входных чисел и останавливать цикл уже по получению этого кол-ва.
Сейчас же программа просто читает данные в бесконечном цикле, а потом, при условии что программа как-то все таки покинет цикл,  делит summ на a, который, кстати, равен 0 и кончается.
Перепишите код исходя из того что вам сказали в ответе, который, кстати, решил изначальную проблему вопроса, так что можете поставить на нем галку.

Answer (score 7):

Как по мне, здесь неправильное использование метода `nextInt()`

`sc.nextInt()` - метод для получения интового представления набора символа, полученного из представленного потока

`sc.nextInt(int radix)` - метод для получения интового представления набора символа, полученого из представленного потока, в СС по основанию переданного как параметр метода `nextInt(int radix)`

Для решения проблемы просто замени `int ch = sc.nextInt(a + 1)` на `int ch = sc.nextInt()`

Да и цикл таки не закончил первую итерацию, так как после первого вызова `nextInt()` кидается исключение `InputMismatchException` и метод вынужден прерваться и кинуть исключение.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Введите числа для вычисления \nсреднего арифметического!!!");
    int a = 0;
    int summ = 0;

    while (true) {
        System.out.print("число " + (a + 1) + ": ");
        int ch = sc.nextInt();
        if (ch == 0) {
            break;
        }
        summ += ch;
        a++;
    }

    int i = summ / a;
    int j = summ % a;
    if (summ % a == 0)
        System.out.println("Ответ : " + i);
    else
        System.out.println("Ответ : " + i + " с остатком : " + j);

    sc.close();
}
```

Вот так все работает. Ошибка была в sc.nextInt(a + 1) и в логике программы